# insert a line into xml using xmlstarlet

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

I have an XML file which looks like so:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!-- Solr managed schema - automatically generated - DO NOT EDIT -->
    <schema name="default-config" version="1.6">
      <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
     ....
```

I would like to insert this line:

```
<similarity class="solr.BM25SimilarityFactory"/>
```

between `<schema.. and <uniqueKey` like so:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!-- Solr managed schema - automatically generated - DO NOT EDIT -->
    <schema name="default-config" version="1.6">
    <similarity class="solr.BM25SimilarityFactory"/>
      <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
```

I am trying to do this using xmlstarlet, but not having much luck :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two steps (I fold line for readability)

```
xmlstarlet ed -s "//schema" -t elem -n "similarity"  \
              -i "//similarity" -t attr -n "class" -v "solr.BM25SimilarityFactory"  \
 > final.xml
```

note the use of `-s` (`subnode`).

note also that line was added at the end, but it should be no problem for xmlparser.

You may wish to look at [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5954168/how-to-insert-a-new-element-under-another-with-xmlstarlet).